# UnLua delegate has a few lines of code that I can't read. I hope someone can help me with my answer

Tags: lua

```
Notifier_C.AutoRemoveEvent = function(widget, messageId, callback)
    if messageId == nil or widget == nil or callback == nil then
        return
    end


    local objectEvents = Notifier_C.eventsMap[messageId]

    if objectEvents == nil then
        objectEvents = {}
        Notifier_C.eventsMap[messageId] = objectEvents
    end

    if Notifier_C.eventIdsMap[messageId] == nil then
        Notifier_C.eventIdsMap[messageId] = messageId
    end

    objectEvents[#objectEvents + 1] = {widget, callback}

    local objectfuncs = Notifier_C.objectFuncMap[widget]

    if objectfuncs == nil then
        objectfuncs = {}
        Notifier_C.objectFuncMap[widget] = objectfuncs
    end

    objectfuncs[callback] = callback

    --Notifier_C.Dump()
end
```

Comment: don't post screenshots of text. post formatted text...  what do you mean you cannot read it? it is readable text. please improve your post

Comment: Has been modified

Comment: but what do you mean with you cannot read it? don't you understand its meaning? its a few simple assignments so I'm not sure what your problem is

Comment: Yes,Such as this:

Comment: if objectEvents == nil then
        objectEvents = {}
        Notifier_C.eventsMap[messageId] = objectEvents
    end

Answer (score 0):

```
local objectEvents = Notifier_C.eventsMap[messageId]
if objectEvents == nil then
  objectEvents = {}
  Notifier_C.eventsMap[messageId] = objectEvents
end
```

This simply checks wether `Notifier_C.eventsMap[messageId]` exists.If not an empty table is assigned.

So first they create a local reference `objectEvents` to `Notifier_C.eventsMap[messageId]`. This is mainly so you can use the shorter `objectEvents` to make code more readable.

Then you check wether that value is a nil value. If that is the case you replace it with an empty table. As later it is expected to be a table.

So an empty table is the default value for `Notifier_C.eventsMap[messageId]`

Comment: do not quite understand

Comment: what is there not to understand? you replace a nil value with an empty table. if you don't understand this you should do some beginners tutorial. this whole code is just a sequence of conditional assignments. you store some values like callback or widget for later use.

Comment: Notifier_C.eventsMap[messageId] Is this value ObjtctEvents?

Comment: Do you have any good courses to recommend? I'm just a beginner

Comment: read Programming in Lua and the Lua Reference Manual. any beginners tutorial on top of that will help, especially if you don't have any prior programming expierience.